# Loss function to use with image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am confused about the appropriate loss function to use as i am generating my dataset using image_dataset_from_directory.

**Data Generator**

Train

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  '/content/dataset/train',
  validation_split=0.05,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Validation

```
val_ds =  tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    '/content/dataset/val', image_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)
```

**Model**

```
rn50v2_model = Sequential()

pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3),
    pooling='avg',
    classes = 2
)

print(pretrained_model.summary())

rn50v2_model.add(pretrained_model)

rn50v2_model.add(Flatten())

rn50v2_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

rn50v2_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

#print(rn50v2_model.summary())

rn50v2_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

when i tested my model, i got my result one hot encoded like below:

```
array([[0.24823777, 0.7517622 ]], dtype=float32)
```

I would prefer to use  `categorical_crossentropy` but pls explain this behaviour i cant seem to find information on the official documentation

Comment: Explain what behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is not one hot encoded. It is the result of your output layer squished by the softmax function. This function transforms all values between 0 and 1 and these values sum to 1. You can apply `np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)` to these "probabilities" to get the corresponding class. To use `categorical_crossentropy`, try changing your `label_mode` to `categorical`, which will automatically generated one-hot-encoded labels:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  '/content/dataset/train',
  validation_split=0.05,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  label_mode = 'categorical',
  image_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

val_ds =  tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    '/content/dataset/val', 
     subset="validation",
     seed=123, 
     label_mode = 'categorical',
     image_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), 
     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

You could also consider using `binary_crossentropy` if you only have two classes. You would have to change your loss function and output layer:

```
rn50v2_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Brilliant! thanks, i was trying to avoid use of sigmoid to avoid vanishing gradient, are my concerns valid?

Comment: if using sigmoid will my label still be `
categorical`?

Comment: Vanishing gradients are common when the Sigmoid function is used in the hidden layers. Using it in the output layer is not a problem.

Comment: Your labels would be binary or categorical. 0 belongs to class-x and 1 belongs to class-y, but don't want to confuse you.

Comment: loss='binary_crossentropy'

Comment: what label_mode to go for?

Comment: For `binary` and `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` use `label_mode=int`. For `categorical_crossentropy` use `label_mode = 'categorical'`.

Comment: Gracias, Obrigado, Danke, Thanks!